# Time difference between clock in punches

Tags: mysql

I have the code bellow which functions just fine. I am one step away from completing it but I can't figure out the best approach for the task at hand. MySQL? PHP? JavaScript?

Here's my table:

[image]

As you can see, field UTL_DURATION is empty.

Description:

As is, each time the user inserts a record, every field is populated except UTL_DURATION. This is because UTL_DURATION is a calculation.

Question

How can I, (in which language is this best done in)? How can one obtain the UTL_DTSTAMP from the **previously inserted record** and compare it to the **currently being inserted UTL_DTSTAMP** from the current record?

Something similar to...

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2017-12-16 08:33:55','2017-12-16 08:33:49') AS UTL_DURATION;
```

...tells us how long a user spent on a SALE.

I hope I made sense,

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Update 3

**TBL_USER_TIME_LOG**

[image: TBL_USER_TIME_LOG]

**CUSTOM SELECT QUERY**

```
SELECT A.pk_user_time_log_id,
       A.user_id,
       A.utl_dtstamp,
       A.utl_event,
       A.utl_action,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, A.utl_dtstamp, B.utl_dtstamp) AS UTL_DURATION_IN_HRS,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, A.utl_dtstamp, B.utl_dtstamp) AS UTL_DURATION_IN_MIN,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, A.utl_dtstamp, B.utl_dtstamp) AS UTL_DURATION_IN_SEC
FROM   tbl_user_time_log A
       INNER JOIN tbl_user_time_log B
               ON B.pk_user_time_log_id = ( A.pk_user_time_log_id + 1 )
ORDER  BY A.pk_user_time_log_id ASC;
```

**CUSTOM SELECT QUERY RESULT**

[image]

Other thoughts

Perhaps there may be a way to CONCATENATE our last three result fields into one and format the string to look more like a military time.

Comment: Looks like you achieved what you wanted to, right? What output do you get when the `USER_ID` changes, or is that not an issue?

Comment: Just add a WHERE clause after FROM clause.